# Why do I have problems as long as I define class Intsize in the @compose function

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun test(
    size: IntSize = IntSize(0,0)
){

}
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fuu_library.test, PID: 19182
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Composable Method 'com.example.fuu_library.LoadableButtonKt.LoadableButton' not found
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposable(ComposableInvoker.kt:203)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.PreviewActivity$setComposableContent$2.invoke(PreviewActivity.kt:74)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.PreviewActivity$setComposableContent$2.invoke(PreviewActivity.kt:73)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:404)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:250)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:249)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3248)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
2023-08-20 21:25:25.506 19182-19182 AndroidRuntime          com.example.fuu_library.test         E      at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3173)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:587)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:950)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1060)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1147)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.fuu_library.LoadableButtonKt.LoadableButton
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.findComposableMethod(ComposableInvoker.kt:83)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposable(ComposableInvoker.kt:190)
... 66 more